# ruby on rails, how to display content only one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <span class="content"><%= post.name %></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this can bring the name in the Model Post and display it. However sometimes the name is too long to display in one line. Then it will be showed in two lines and it will destroy my page. What I want to know is how to make it only display one line no matter how long the name is. When the name is too long, it will just display part of it. And when people move their mouse on it, it will show the whole name.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any css file?

Comment: I am using bootstrap from Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is with `String#truncate`.

You could limit the string to, say 50 characters, with `post.name.truncate(50)`, and you can use the `title` attribute in your content span to display the rest of the string when the user moves the mouse over:

```
<span class="content" title="<%= post.name %>"><%= post.name.truncate(50) %></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browser you need to target, you can use text-overflow property of CSS. More info and example is available in "[Elegant Overflow with CSS Ellipsis](http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis)".

Otherwise, you can use Rails' [`String#truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) addition